# Console application not waiting on async delay?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I wanted to add a delay to my server when disposing so that users could actually read the shutdown message, and I couldn't do it with thread sleep as it would freeze the whole game.

I decided to change my functionality to use an async task, but it seems like its just closing instantly, and not even disposing which is a real feature kill.

First, I check for a key input that tells me to shutdown or reboot...

```
var rebootAfterClose = false;

while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadKey();

    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.C && input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (input.Key != ConsoleKey.R || input.Modifiers != ConsoleModifiers.Control)
    {
        continue;
    }

    rebootAfterClose = true;
    break;
}

Server?.Stop(rebootAfterClose);
```

I then have the code that actually shuts down

```
public async Task Stop(bool restart)
{
    var shutdownMessage = PlusEnvironment.GetLanguageManager().TryGetValue("server.shutdown.message");
    var shutdownPacket = new BroadcastMessageAlertComposer(shutdownMessage);

    Program.Server.BaseHandler.PlayerHandler.SendPacketToPlayers(shutdownPacket);

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    // TODO: Start the process if restart = true

    Dispose();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (Disposing)
    {
        return;
    }

    Disposing = true;

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Title = "Server is shutting down...";

    Logger.Warn("Server is shutting down...");

    BaseHandler.PlayerHandler.Dispose();
    ConsoleUpdater.Dispose();
    SocketHandler.Dispose();

    PlusEnvironment.OnShutDown();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: your `stop` method returns you `Task`, not a particular result. you have to add `?.Wait()`

Comment: I think you'd want to do `await Server?.Stop(rebootAfterClose);` If I'm not mistaken `.Wait()` will stop the thread just as much as a `Thread.Sleep`. I'm not 100% sure though

Comment: @FrancisLord That depends:  If that code is from `Main`, then you can't `await`.

Comment: oh true. Still, doing a wait might not fix his issue

Comment: To wait for async methods inside `Main` use Server?.Stop(rebootAfterClose).GetAwaiter().GetResult();